# Docker-Compose service reference of mysql db not working in flask service: name 'mysqldb' not defined

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, containers

My Docker-compose file looks like this, with the `web` service being the Flask Server, and the `mysqldb` service referencing a mysql server running in a separate container:

```
version: '3'

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: testing
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testing
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
  web:
      restart: always
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      expose:
          - "5000"
      links:
        - mysqldb
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
```

According to documentation, I should be able to write `mysqldb` in my flask-service.py file as a variable like this:

```
...
import mysql.connector
...
print(mysqldb)
mysqlcnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='testing', password='testing', host= mysqldb, 
                                port = '3306',database='test' )
...
```

But instead upon running `docker-compose up --build -d`, my logs for the web service show

```
NameError: name `mysqldb` is not defined
```

I looked through several stack overflow questions and docker examples, but I can't find a solid reason that the reference does not work. I also tried importing `os` and calling it as if it was an environment variable, to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to refer the name `mysqldb` as python variable which ofcourse would not be found because you have not defined it anywhere in your code. You will be able to connect to DB using `mysqldb` as hostname because docker-compose sets up the network between the services. So change the line `host= mysqldb` to `host='mysqldb'`